# How to change API data which is in object type to array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-datatable

ERROR: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `rows` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef`, expected an array.

Here is my code...

```
import React,{useState,useEffect}  from "react";
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const columns=[
    {field:'_id', headerName:'ID'},
    {field:'firstName',headerName:"FirstName", width:300},
    {field:'lastName',headerName:"LastName", width:600},
    {field:'email', headerName:"Email", width:700}
]





const DataTable=()=>{
 
    const[tableData,setTableData]=useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3333/entry')
        .then((data)=>data.json())
        .then((data)=>setTableData(data))
    },[])
   
console.log(tableData);


    return(
        <div  style={{height:600, width:'99%'}}> 
            <h1>Data Table</h1>
            <DataGrid  getRowId={(r) => r._id} rows={tableData} columns={columns}  checkboxSelection/>
            </div>
    )
}

export default DataTable
```

Comment: Could you add an example of data received from the API (object printed by `console.log` statement)? It would be really useful as now I can only guess the shape of it.

Comment: if the `data.json()` returns the object you can't assign it to array. do `setTableData([...data]`). let me know if it works

Comment: @Aitwar it is like this...0: {_id: '61ed510567dafa64d6eda7b1', firstName: 'Ishita', lastName: 'Roy', email: 'ishita@gmail.com', __v: 0}
1: {_id: '61ed91ca12d18c525803b8b2', firstName: 'trisha', lastName: 'roy', email: 'trisha@gmail.com', __v: 0}

Comment: @abhipatil it is showing me error that data is not iterable...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.